# mysqldump exports all tables as seperate .sql files in one command

Tags: mysql

I need to know to how to export all the tables in the database as .sql files using mysqldump. i need to set them into separate files per table for easy restore process.

Please note that there is over 100+ tables in the database that following option is NOT GOING to help me.

```
mysqldump -p --user=username dbname tableName > tableName.sql
```

**Note:
Also prefer a Single Command rather than set of commands in shell scripts with forloops.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysqldump does not have an option to dump a separate .sql file per table.

You can use `mysqldump --tab` to dump a separate CSV file per table (but keep in mind this dumps the files on the database server, not on the host where you run the command, so it won't work for example if you use RDS).

You can also use [mydumper](https://github.com/maxbube/mydumper) which is an open-source tool. This dumps two .sql files for each table: one with the CREATE TABLE definition, and a second file that contains the data.